# Google Maps API : Code stops work after making a change

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got these code. Using Google Maps API together with additional, self-written CSS-, JavaScript-code:

```js
// [START region_initialization]
// This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
// a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.

// Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
// of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
// it's simpler to load the API synchronously, using
// google.maps.event.addDomListener().
// Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
// parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.

var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map'), {
 zoom: 16,
 center: {lat: 49.2164353, lng: 6.9752852},
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
   new google.maps.LatLng(49.212860, 6.969140),
   new google.maps.LatLng(49.219644, 6.982938)
  );
  // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
  var srcImage = 'imgs/ground_plan.jpg';

  // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
  // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}
// [END region_initialization]

// [START region_constructor]
/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}
// [END region_constructor]

// [START region_attachment]
/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
// [END region_attachment]

// [START region_drawing]
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
  
  // Die CSS-property legt die Durchsichtigkeit eines Elementes fest.
  // 1.0 => Keine Durchsichtigkeit.
  // 0.0 => Vollkommene Durchsichtkeit.
  div.style.opacity = '0.5';
  
  // Positive Zahl => Dreht im Uhrzeigersinn.
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(17deg)';
};
// [END region_drawing]

// [START region_removal]
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
// [END region_removal]

USGSOverlay.prototype.hide = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
 // The visibility property must be a string enclosed in quotes.
 this.div_.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.show = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
 this.div_.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.toggle = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
 if (this.div_.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
   this.show();
 } else {
   this.hide();
 }
  }
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

var toggleButton = document.querySelector('#toggleOverlay');
var increaseButton = document.querySelector('#increaseOpacity');
var decreaseButton = document.querySelector('#decreaseOpacity');
var opacityDisplay = document.querySelector('#current-opacity');

function updateDisplay() { 
 opacityDisplay.innerHTML =
    parseFloat(overlay.div_.style['opacity']).toFixed(1);
}

function setOpacity(step, limit) {
 let currentStyle = overlay.div_.style;
 let opacity = parseFloat(currentStyle['opacity']); // currentStyle['opacity'] is a STRING !!

 if (opacity !== limit) {
   opacity += step // Calculation has to be done ONLY with numbers because STRING + NUMBER results in a string.
   currentStyle['opacity'] = opacity; // The number will be converted into a string.
   
   updateDisplay();

   if (opacityDisplay.classList.contains('limit-reached')) {
    opacityDisplay.classList.remove('limit-reached');
   } 
 } else {
   opacityDisplay.classList.add('limit-reached');
 }
}

increaseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 setOpacity(-0.1, 0.0);
});

decreaseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 setOpacity(0.1, 1.0);
});

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 let current = overlay.div_.style.visibility;
 let that = this;

 function setValues(that, visibleVal, newButtonText) {
   overlay.div_.style.visibility = visibleVal;
   that.textContent = newButtonText;
 }

 current === 'hidden' ?
   setValues(that, 'visible', 'hide overlay') :
   setValues(that, 'hidden', 'show overlay');
});
  
opacityDisplay.addEventListener('load', updateDisplay);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

body {
  background-color: #d9d9d9; }

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

nav {
  margin: 5px 10px; }

#map {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black; }

a.default-button {
  text-decoration: none; }

#current-opacity, .default-button {
  font-family: Segoe UI, Frutiger, Frutiger Linotype, Dejavu Sans, Helvetica;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #4367c5;
  border: 3px solid #4367c5;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px; }

#current-opacity {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative; }

#current-opacity:after {
  content: attr(data-hint);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: crimson;
  left: 80%;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid crimson;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px #646464;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  transform: rotate(5deg); }

#current-opacity.limit-reached:after {
  display: block; }

.default-button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 150px; }

.default-button:hover {
  color: #009e60;
  border-color: #009e60; }

.default-button:active {
  opacity: 0.6; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Werk 1 - Saarbrücken</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
    
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="wrap">
   <nav class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="default-button" id="toggleOverlay">Hide overlay</a>
    <a href="#" class="default-button" id="increaseOpacity">Increase opacity</a>
    <a href="#" class="default-button" id="decreaseOpacity">Decrease opacity</a>
    <div id="current-opacity" data-hint="Limit reached">0.5</div>
   </nav>
   <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AFDi434FSDFASFD343434af&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*The JPG, used as an overlay, the correct API-key I can't include. Could get me into trouble. Sorry.*

My problem is: I make any changes to the code (changing the image-path, changing the coordinates for center / the overlay) and the **whole thing stops to keep working.**

After making changes: The map stays empty.

[image: Map stays empty]

**What is going on there? What I'm doing wrong?**

Especially: What do I have to do to get it working **with** code-changes?

[image: Encoding used]

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: No. Nothing at all. So not the slightest hint.  :(  Haven't had something like that before ...

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you're changing? If it's anything at all - are you saving the file as an UTF-8 encoded, and not ANSI?

Comment: Trying to change the bounds of the overlay for example: "var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
   new google.maps.LatLng(49.212860, 6.969140),
   new google.maps.LatLng(49.219644, 6.982938)
  );" But trying to change the path to the overlay (" var srcImage = 'imgs/ground_plan.jpg'; " ) has the same effect: The map disappears (see screenshot).

Comment: The encoding of the editor I've got here (Notepad++) says "Encode in ANSI". See please added Screenshot in my question! Do you think there could be a relation with the encoding?

Comment: @mizech - I thought that when changing the encoding your editor added some characters that would error out the JS. But, given the accepted invalid key answer my hypotesis is that, when testing it on your local you've viewed the cached version of your page (that's why the code was working), but when deploying the code, the browser retrieved an updated version of page from the server (due to difference in encodings), which combined with a key that recently exceeded quota would explain such behaviour. It's just a guess though. You can test it out by `ctrl+r`ing local page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the key because it was giving an invalid key error. I tried changing the center point and the bounds and the code seems to be working.

```js
// [START region_initialization]
// This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
// a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.

// Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
// of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
// it's simpler to load the API synchronously, using
// google.maps.event.addDomListener().
// Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
// parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.

var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map'), {
 zoom: 9,
 center: {lat: 19.2164353, lng: 72.9752852},
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
   new google.maps.LatLng(19.212860, 72.969140),
   new google.maps.LatLng(19.219644, 72.982938)
  );
  // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
  var srcImage = 'imgs/ground_plan.jpg';

  // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
  // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}
// [END region_initialization]

// [START region_constructor]
/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}
// [END region_constructor]

// [START region_attachment]
/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
// [END region_attachment]

// [START region_drawing]
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
  
  // Die CSS-property legt die Durchsichtigkeit eines Elementes fest.
  // 1.0 => Keine Durchsichtigkeit.
  // 0.0 => Vollkommene Durchsichtkeit.
  div.style.opacity = '0.5';
  
  // Positive Zahl => Dreht im Uhrzeigersinn.
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(17deg)';
};
// [END region_drawing]

// [START region_removal]
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
// [END region_removal]

USGSOverlay.prototype.hide = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
 // The visibility property must be a string enclosed in quotes.
 this.div_.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.show = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
 this.div_.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.toggle = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
 if (this.div_.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
   this.show();
 } else {
   this.hide();
 }
  }
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

var toggleButton = document.querySelector('#toggleOverlay');
var increaseButton = document.querySelector('#increaseOpacity');
var decreaseButton = document.querySelector('#decreaseOpacity');
var opacityDisplay = document.querySelector('#current-opacity');

function updateDisplay() { 
 opacityDisplay.innerHTML =
    parseFloat(overlay.div_.style['opacity']).toFixed(1);
}

function setOpacity(step, limit) {
 let currentStyle = overlay.div_.style;
 let opacity = parseFloat(currentStyle['opacity']); // currentStyle['opacity'] is a STRING !!

 if (opacity !== limit) {
   opacity += step // Calculation has to be done ONLY with numbers because STRING + NUMBER results in a string.
   currentStyle['opacity'] = opacity; // The number will be converted into a string.
   
   updateDisplay();

   if (opacityDisplay.classList.contains('limit-reached')) {
    opacityDisplay.classList.remove('limit-reached');
   } 
 } else {
   opacityDisplay.classList.add('limit-reached');
 }
}

increaseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 setOpacity(-0.1, 0.0);
});

decreaseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 setOpacity(0.1, 1.0);
});

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 let current = overlay.div_.style.visibility;
 let that = this;

 function setValues(that, visibleVal, newButtonText) {
   overlay.div_.style.visibility = visibleVal;
   that.textContent = newButtonText;
 }

 current === 'hidden' ?
   setValues(that, 'visible', 'hide overlay') :
   setValues(that, 'hidden', 'show overlay');
});
  
opacityDisplay.addEventListener('load', updateDisplay);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

body {
  background-color: #d9d9d9; }

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

nav {
  margin: 5px 10px; }

#map {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black; }

a.default-button {
  text-decoration: none; }

#current-opacity, .default-button {
  font-family: Segoe UI, Frutiger, Frutiger Linotype, Dejavu Sans, Helvetica;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #4367c5;
  border: 3px solid #4367c5;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px; }

#current-opacity {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative; }

#current-opacity:after {
  content: attr(data-hint);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: crimson;
  left: 80%;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid crimson;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px #646464;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  transform: rotate(5deg); }

#current-opacity.limit-reached:after {
  display: block; }

.default-button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 150px; }

.default-button:hover {
  color: #009e60;
  border-color: #009e60; }

.default-button:active {
  opacity: 0.6; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Werk 1 - Saarbrücken</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
    
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="wrap">
   <nav class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="default-button" id="toggleOverlay">Hide overlay</a>
    <a href="#" class="default-button" id="increaseOpacity">Increase opacity</a>
    <a href="#" class="default-button" id="decreaseOpacity">Decrease opacity</a>
    <div id="current-opacity" data-hint="Limit reached">0.5</div>
   </nav>
   <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned that more clear in my question: I insert some arbitrary chars for the key. Because the key belongs the project and I'm not allowed to give it to outwards. After reading your answer I've removed the (real) key at all. Now working WITHOUT any key-parameter in the src URL ( https://maps.googleapis.com ... ) . It works now!! Somehow the problem was connected with the key.

Comment: @mizech - bear in mind that Google allows for the usage of map without key if given domain doesn't exceed a certain quota. It will stop working without key, if the quota is exceeded (25k views, but we've reached that threshold quite fast for a website that was just deployed, that didn't really record much of ingoing traffic).

Comment: Ensure that you have a valid key and that you have added your website in the referrer list in the Google Maps API console. Always use a valid key when using Google Maps API

Comment: @eithedog : It will be used for a enterprise intranet. Not public internet. So there isn't too much traffic to expect. But I will keep your hint in mind. Thanks a bunch. :) It's good to know in any case.

Comment: It might be that Google are limiting the usage of Maps way below the 25k without a valid key (for development purposes for example). I couldn't find any information about it though

Comment: @Joyson Thanks. Currently I'm happy that I can on with developing. But I have to find a way deploying it WITH key. You're right.